# LWC update toggle checked/unchecked attribute from JS

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, radio-button, attribute

First of all I’m new to LWC development so I would like to apologize if the question looks stupid.
I’m currently working on a LWC and I would like to create 2 toggles but I want only one toggle to be checked at the same time (same as a radio button group) but I need to have the style of the toggles

[image]

I didn’t find an easy way to use radio button and change the css checkbox so I’m using 2 input toggle.
The current Idea is to put an Id on the toggle and change their checked/unchecked attributes when any of the other is changed.
My problem right now is that I can’t succeed to update any Html attribute from the Javascript controler .

My code is below:

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle" label="TOGGLE1" onchange={changeToggle} unchecked message-toggle-active="" message-toggle-inactive="" ></lightning-input> <br/>
<lightning-input data-id="toggle2" type="toggle" label="TOGGLE2" onchange={changeToggle} unchecked message-toggle-active="" message-toggle-inactive=""></lightning-input> <br/>
```

```
changeToggle(event) {
        console.log('event.target: ',event.target);
        console.log('event.target.checked: ',event.target.checked);
        console.log('event.target.label: ',event.target.label);

        const element = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="toggle1"]'); 
        console.log('element: ' , element.checked);
        console.log('element: ' , element.label);
        element.setAttribute('checked', false);
        element.setAttribute('unchecked', true);
        console.log('element: ' , element.checked);

    }
```

When I have toggle 1 enabled and I enable the second One here is what I see on the log:

[image]

Is there another way to update Html Attribute other than set element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just bind the `checked` attribute to javascript property.

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle2" type="toggle" label="TOGGLE2" checked={checked} message-toggle-active="" message-toggle-inactive=""></lightning-input> <br/>
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle" label="Click Me" onchange={changeToggle} message-toggle-active="" message-toggle-inactive="" ></lightning-input> <br/>
```

Update that value from the js method like this.

```
@track checked = true;
changeToggle(event){
    this.checked = !this.checked;
}
```

See the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Zw01KEh0y/2/edit)

Comment: Pretty simple indeed, I was thinking that i couldn't add a value to the checked attribute... 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Julien Most welcome!